# Go app graceful restart with systemd (and endless)

Tags: go, systemd

I want to do real graceful restart for Go application, while still being able to control it with systemd. I'm using [endless](https://github.com/fvbock/endless) in the app. The code is trivial (`endless.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)`), and for the systemd config file, so far I managed to make it like this (goapp.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Go Application
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/root/go/src/myproject
ExecStart=/root/go/src/myproject/goapp
KillSignal=SIGHUP
Restart=on-failure
```

Then I just start the app with `systemctl start goapp`, everything's fine, but when I issue `systemctl restart goapp` while giving the application tons of requests at the same time, the restart command seems to hang my terminal (and not kill/fork the process) until it's free from requests. Of course, when there are no requests, the service restarts successfully.

I'm testing with this simple code:

```
package main   

import "net/http"
import "github.com/fvbock/endless"

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    endless.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

Could anyone help with this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you'd need to include all of your applications code in order to get that... If you have goroutines your app will not reset gracefully unless you have code forcing all of them to return when the application wants to shut down.

Comment: Sorry, that comment above is somewhat unclear. I don't know because none of your actual source is included here, however, in my experience, a Go application cannot shutdown/restart until all active goroutines return. I've handled this by making all my async functions accept an abort channel and do all of their work from within a channel select where they listen for abort. If you have started goroutines and have no way to *make them return* when the restart command is issued then you will not be able to shut down gracefully.

Comment: OK I would speculate that `endless`' implementation of `ListenAndServe` is leaking goroutines but I'll take a look at their source.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do, do you want systemctl restart to actually kill and start the process again, or do you want it to do a graceful restart ?

Comment: @nos I want it to do graceful restart.

Comment: The fact that the command hangs until it's free from requests *is* a graceful restart. The point is to try and wait until there are no open connections, which is why "endless" has `DefaultHammerTime` to eventually kill the connection. I personally don't like or use this type of "graceful" restart on a busy server, since it adds a lot of complication, and you will always end up having to drop connections anyway.